# Points and dual $\mathbb{R}$-algebra to $\mathbb{R}[V]$ on real affine variety $V$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a real affine variety with its ring $\mathbb{R}[V]$ of regular functions. Denote by $|\mathbb{R}[V]|$ the set of all $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphisms $h:\mathbb{R}[V]\to \mathbb{R}.$

Any point $x\in V$ induces element $ev_x\in|\mathbb{R}[V]|$ beeing the evaluation map at $x$. I.e. $ev_x(f)=f(x).$

> **Question.** Do all elements from $|\mathbb{R}[V]|$ are of form $ev_x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $V \subset \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^n$, and consider the ideal $I(V) \subset \mathbb{R}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$. Then $\mathbb{R}[V] \cong \mathbb{R}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]/I(V)$. Let $\overline{f}$ denote the image of $f\in \mathbb{R}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$ in $\mathbb{R}[V]$.

Since $\mathbb{R}[V]$ is generated by $\overline{x_k}$ for $1\le k \le n$, any $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R}[V]\to \mathbb{R}$ is entirely determined by the images of the $\overline{x_k}$.

If $\phi(\overline{x_k}) = c_k$, then for any regular function $\overline{f}(x_1, \cdots, x_n)\in \mathbb{R}[V]$, we have $$\phi(\overline{f}(x_1, \cdots, x_n)) = f(\phi(\overline{x_1}), \cdots, \phi(\overline{x_n})) = f(c_1, \cdots, c_n)$$

Set $x := (c_1, \cdots, c_n) \in \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^n$. Notice that for any $g\in I(V)$, we have $g(x) = \phi(\overline{g}) = \phi(0) = 0$. Thus, in fact $x \in V$.

We conclude $\phi = \text{ev}_x$ for $x\in V$.

Comment: Great! I didn't suspect that the answer can be so neat. Very thanks!

Comment: Btw. Is it the standard reasoning from some textbook or you came up with the solution? I was cursorily looking for the answer in the Eisenbud, but I faild to find any.

Comment: Hi! I need this fact in my paper, but obviously I don't want to take credit for this. Do you know any references of this fact or do you came up with the solution?